# Looking for a simplest way to transfer binary data using C++ API between 2 Linux PCs connected directly with Ethernet cable

Tags: windows, linux, python, c++, networking

I have 2 Ubuntu 23.10 PCs connected directly with a crossover (or regular) Ethernet cable. Each of them have a static IP address set. `ping` command works as expected. I'm looking for a simple way to transfer binary blobs of varying length from PC #1 to PC #2, each running a C++ code. The final setup will be the sender PC running C++ on Linux and the receiver PC running Python on Windows. Security is not a concern, since this is an isolated network. Simplicity and a low learning curve is my objective. Sender has to be able to do asynchronous writes. I have very little experience with networking and I'm looking for library and OS configuration recommendations.

So far, I found these options:

- low level socket API
- ZeroMQ

Comment: And you don't want SSH or RSync, because the main goal of this is ... what exactly? Learning C++, learning Python, ... ?

Comment: @ThomasWeller I didn't write *don't want SSH or RSync*. Will take a look at these. Need at least 2500 transactions per second, asynchronous calls.